# Sampling Covariance of two sample variances (for a finite population and a small N[population size]))

Tags: variance, covariance, survey-sampling

What is the expression for the sampling covariance of two sample variances i.e. $\operatorname{Cov}(s_1^2, s_2^2)$. Where $s_1^2=\frac {1}{n-1} \sum(x_i-\bar x )^2$ and $s_2^2=\frac {1}{n-1} \sum(y_i-\bar y )^2$?

Comment: Welcome to our site! You can use Latex to typeset your equations here - I've edited yours for you.

Comment: I don't think it is meaningful to seek  the `sample covariance` of two sample variances. Given a set of data $((X_1,Y_1), ..., (X_n, Y_n))$, $s_1^2$ is an estimator that will produce a single number, and $s_2^2$ is an estimator that will produce a single number. What then is the _sample covariance_ between those 2 single numbers?   One can, by contrast, define and calculate the theoretical covariance between the estimators $s_1^2$ and $s_2^2$ ,,, namely $Cov(s_1^2,s_2^2)$   -  but that is not _sample covariance_ that you refer to in the question .

Comment: @wolfies: Am referring to sampling covariance of any two sample variances. Recall that any characteristic f(x1, x2,...,xn) of an actual sample may be regarded as an observed value of a random variable f(x1, x2,...,xn), where x1, x2,...,xn are independent variables, all having the same distribution as the orignal variable say ɛ. [...Cont'd below]

Comment: The distribution of the random variable f(x1, x2,...,xn) is called the SAMPLING DISTRIBUTION of the characteristic f(x1, x2,...,xn). Thus we may talk of the sampling distribution of the mean x{bar} e.g. Var(x{bar}), the sampling distribution of the variance s^2 e.g. Var(s^2) and Cov(s1^2,s2^2), etc. Trust this throws more light...

Comment: I was not commenting on your use of the term `sampling distribution` ... but your term:  /// `"sample covariance of two sample variances"` ///, when in fact you are not seeking the `sample covariance` of the two sample variances, but just their formal theoretical covariance $\operatorname{Cov}(s_1^2, s_2^2)$. I see you have now removed the term `sample covariance` - thanks - that does help clarify the question.

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem of finding *moments of moments*. Given a sample of size $n$, namely $((X_1, Y_1), \dots, (X_n, Y_n))$, we seek the covariance:

$$\text{ Cov}\big(\frac{1}{n-1}\sum _{i=1}^n \left(X_i-\bar{X}\right)^2, \frac{1}{n-1}\sum _{i=1}^n \left(Y_i-\bar{Y}\right)^2\big)$$

The *modus operandi* for solving such problems is to work with power sum notation $s_{r,t}$, namely:

$$s_{r,t}=\sum _{i=1}^n X_i^r Y_i^t$$

Let:

- $m_{20} = \frac{1}{n-1}\sum _{i=1}^n \left(X_i-\bar{X}\right){}^2 \left(Y_i-\bar{Y}\right){}^0$ and
- $m_{02} = \frac{1}{n-1}\sum _{i=1}^n \left(X_i-\bar{X}\right){}^0 \left(Y_i-\bar{Y}\right){}^2$

... denote our two unbiased estimators of the variance of $X$ and $Y$ respectively, which can be expressed in power sum notation as:

[image]

**Solution**

The covariance operator is just the $\mu_{1,1}$ central moment ... so:

- $\text{Cov}(m_{20},m_{02})$ is given by:

[image]

where:

- $\mu _{r,s}$ denotes the product central moment:

$$\mu _{r,s}=E\left[(X-E[X]]^r (Y-E[Y])^s\right]$$

... so $\mu_{1,1} = \text{Cov}(X,Y)$, $\mu_{2,0}= Var(X)$ and $\mu_{0,2}= Var(Y)$

- `CentralMomentToCentral` is a function from the *mathStatica* package for *Mathematica*.

The OP further notes that he is sampling from a finite population. Presumably this means *without replacement*. This requires a further 'weighting' adjustment, typically something like $ \frac{N}{N-1}$ where $N$ denotes the finite population size, reducing to the above solution as $N$ becomes large. The extension to modify results to finite populations *without replacement* can be done by the Irwin-Kendall principle ... a discussion of which is provided in Stuart and Ord: *Kendall's Advanced Theory of Statistics* - volume 1 (6th edition) at Section 12.20 and 12.21.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Please how can one derive this manually without the help of the software. Now I think my challenge is on grabbing this power sum notation approach. please explain further in simple terms. Thanks.

Comment: Chapters 12 and 13 of Stuart and Ord are your friend. It is not something that can readily be described on stackexcahnge - the derivation of solutions is complicated, and rapidly becomes extremely tedious to do by hand, which is why software (or tables, if you can find them, for your problem) is a better approach.

Comment: I haved surfed the web. I was only able to get the 3rd edition (Vol.1) of the referred book. Can you help a brother with the PDF version of the 6th edition. My mail ad is macnewton2k3@yahoo.com. Warm regards.

Comment: I'm sure the 3rd edition will suffice. If not, just find a good university library.